# Infinite loop при обновлении store ngrx

Tags: angular2, angular, rxjs

В компонент приходят данные из стора (ngrx)

```
  data$: Observable<Data | undefined>
```

В шаблоне мы их читаем, выводим

```
 data$ | async
```

По клику в шаблоне вызываем метод updateData, который диспатичит action и из effects идут данные на сервер, возвращается ответ, обновляет стор и соотв. обновляется data$

```
  updateData(count) {
    if (this.data$) {
      this.data$.subscribe(detals => {
        this.store.dispatch(newData(dtails.item, count))
      }
    }
  }
```

Данная реализация метода вызывает infinite loop (постоянные вызовы на сервер)

Такой способ работает, но я думаю, что в моем случае это не совсем верное решение.

```
  updateData(count) {
   if (this.data$) {
    this.data$
     .pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(detals => {
      this.store.dispatch(newData(dtails.item, count))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: какой инфинит луп?) да и к тому же этот инфинит луп оправдан - у тебя апдейтится стейт, диспатчится экшн, апдейтится стейт, диспатчится экшн ))

Comment: Идут постоянные вызовы на сервер, я это имел в виду)

Comment: не делай того, что ты делаешь сейчас - `this.data$.subscribe`

Comment: Через Behavior Subject доставать данные в компоненте ?

Comment: нет, мне непонятна твоя бизнес логика, стейт апдейтнулся - зачем тебе диспатчить `newData`?) и что диспатчит эта фабрика и какой эффект слушает это событие?

Comment: Чтобы сделать новый вызов на сервер с count, который пришел из темплейта и item из data$

Comment: покажи экшены и эффекты

Comment: Могу тебе в телеграм написать?) Контакт у меня есть

Comment: ....попробуй ))